# Determine if 2 strings are anagrams

Tags: c++

> Write a function that accepts a c-string and a character as parameters. Returns  the number of times the character appears in the string.

I also have to do this in my program:

> Convert strings A and B to all lower case. For each letter in string A, call function on A and B.

This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

char tolower(char c) {

    return c;
}

int countChars(const char* string, char ch)
{
    int count = 0;
    int i;

    int length = strlen(string);

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (string[i] == ch)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    char stringA[50];
    char stringB[50];

    cout << "Please enter first string: ";
    cin.getline(stringA, 50);

    cout << "Please enter second string: ";
    cin.getline(stringB, 50);

    cout << "String 1: " << stringA << endl;
    cout << "String 2: " << stringB << endl;

    if (strcmp(stringA, stringB) == 0) {
        cout << "These strings are anagrams" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "These strings are not anagrams" << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: The `countChars` function looks fine, but you aren't using it in your code. What's the point of writing it if you never use it? Obviously what you are meant to do is use that function to help work out if the two strings are anagrams. Your instructions even give you a big clue how to do it `For each letter in string A, call function on A and B.`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to be more specific. As written, you haven't stated what the problem is or where you're having trouble. See also: [ask], [mre]

Comment: `strcmp` would compare for equality, not anagram: `aba` != `baa` but they are anagrams

Comment: `tolower` is a standard function in the header file `<cctype>` you don't need to write your own version of this function.

Comment: I think to progress this question you need to explain what you are stuck on. Why can't you do what the question tells you to do?

Comment: What is your question? 1) How to check that 2 strings are anagrams? 2) How to count a character's appearance in a string? 3) How to convert a string lowercase? They're all interesting questions, but please choose.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do so in a **simple** and readable way, consider the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

bool is_anagram(std::string s1, std::string s2)
{
    std::sort(s1.begin(), s1.end());
    std::sort(s2.begin(), s2.end());
    return s1 == s2;
}

int main(void)
{
    std::string s1, s2;

    std::cout << "Input first string: ";
    getline(std::cin, s1);

    std::cout << "Input second string: ";
    getline(std::cin, s2);

    if (is_anagram(s1, s2))
        std::cout << "Strings are anagrams." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Strings are NOT anagrams." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The function `is_anagram()` returns `true` when the sorted strings (used `algorithm` library for it) are same.

> **Note:** The strings are case-sensitive. `Hello` and `hello` are different.

Hope it helps you. :D

Comment: sort is at best `O(n.log(n))` complexity. Testing for an anagram can be done with `O(n)`, Also simple sorting assumes that spaces are significant. In multi word anagrams you usually ignore space.

Comment: @MartinYork: counting sort has O(n) complexity :) preprocessing to remove space, change case, can be done in O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Just sort the both the strings and then compare it.

`sort(stringA, stringA+strlen(stringA))`
`sort(stringB, stringB+strlen(stringB))`

just before the if statement.

You were checking if the 2 strings are *exactly* equal. But anagrams can have different arrangement of letters but must have same letters.

Though you need to check may need to check if the 2 strings are same (if you don't consider a string to be an anagram of itself).

PS- a google search would have instantly provided you ans.

Comment: sort is at best `O(n.log(n))` complexity. Testing for an anagram can be done with `O(n)`, Also simple sorting assumes that spaces are significant. In multi word anagrams you usually ignore space.

Comment: Well agreed, but this solution is 2 line addition to his already existing code. So I thought it's better. But I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to count the number of each letter. Note you don't need to count every letter just the ones are in the string. To compare them store the results in a map.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <array>

class AnagramCheck
{
    // I am going to be lazy and use map to store the counts.
    // But you can do this much smarter and get a better complexity
    // by using an array. But that involves more checks
    std::map<char, int> data;
    public:
        explicit AnagramCheck(std::string const& str)
        {
            for(auto x: str) {
                ++data[std::tolower(x)]; // If you want to be smart ignore space/punctuation
            }
        }
        bool operator==(AnagramCheck const& rhs) const
        {
            return data == rhs.data;
        }
};

int main()
{
    std::string         line1;
    std::getline(std::cin, line1);
    AnagramCheck        line1Check(line1);

    std::string         line2;
    std::getline(std::cin, line2);
    AnagramCheck        line2Check(line2);

    if (line1Check == line2Check) {
        std::cout << "Anagram\n";
    }

}
```